# Unable to install updates in Ubuntu server

Tags: 11.10, server, apt, updates

Unable to install Ubuntu server 11.10 updates.

When I try to update using `apt` I get the following error:

```
reading package lists... done
Building dependence tree .... done
E:unable to locate package update
```

Can you please provide a solution?

Comment: What are you specifically trying to install?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the command you use. Something seems to be wrong there.

Comment: When i used the code sudo apt-get update i get the below       "something wicked happened in resolving "in.archive.ubuntu.com "....             (5 - no address associated with hostname ) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E: Unable to locate package update

some times it happens when you have internet connection with proxy. I have encountered the same case with me. Please also check that you are proxy free and configured it so that proxy server allows you.

Code:
**sudo apt-get update**  if it runs, then everything could be installed. 
And Please mention what you are trying to update here... the solution can vary a bit. :)

---

Edited:

Seems like your DNS configuration is unable to resolve the address.Try pinging to this server from Windows/any other Linux DNS Client.It will inform you with IP.Put that IP under /etc/hosts or under /etc/apt/source.list instead of hostname.
Do Check /etc/resolv.conf too.

Comment: When i used the code sudo apt-get update i get the below       "something wicked happened in resolving "in.archive.ubuntu.com "....             (5 - no address associated with hostname ) "

Comment: I have edited with the solution to that plz try the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a DNS problem. Try putting:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

In /etc/resolv.conf and putting:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

In /etc/network/interfaces.